# Spring cloud dataflow - Composite Task with external configuration

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a composite task with two cloud task ( AAA && BBB ).
I want to pass the properties to AAA and BBB task from a directory. 
For example, the usage of "--spring.config.location=directory/" when launching the Spring boot application.

As per the documentation, i understand that we can pass properties using app.CompositeTaskName.taskname.prop1=val1.
But, i want to load a bunch of configuration at launch. 
So, is there a way to launch the tasks with "spring.config.location" argument ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I passed "--spring.config.location" in the task definition of my composite task.

```sh
task create myctr --definition "AAA --spring.config.location=/data/prop/ '*'->BBB"
```

I launched the composite task "myctr" and it referred the property files from the "/data/prop/" directory.

Documentation reference :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-tasks
--> Task Application Parameters